# #include cyclic dependency error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files

I have code structure like this:

resource.h:

```
#include"a.h"
#include"b.h"
#include"c.h"
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef __A__
#define __A__
#include"resource.h"
class B;
class A{
//something uses B
};
#endif
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef __B__
#define __B__
#include"resource.h"
class A;
class B{
//something uses A
}
#endif
```

c.h:

```
#ifndef __C__
#define __C__
#include"resource.h"
class A;
class B;
class C{
//something uses A and B
};
#endif
```

The problem is the following: VS2010 tells me that in c.h, line *#include"resource.h"* causes "resource.h" includes itself.

However, the codes are able to compile and performed as expected. So I am wondering what causes this error intellisense in VS and if there is anyway to remove it.

P.S: I am compiling with VS and there is no compiling error.

Comment: Compiling with *Errorr* ?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is not in the code you've posted but something specific about the actual includes you have.

Comment: Don't use identifiers with leading double underscores; they're reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a header guard on `resource.h`:

```
#ifndef __RESOURCE__
#define __RESOURCE__ 1
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#endif
```

However, double underscores aren't recommended, as they're reserved for the implementation. So I would use `{PROJECTNAME}_RESOURCE_H`. This will also prevent header guard collisions with other projects that don't do this.

Seeing that you're using Visial Studio, I would reccomend you don't use header guards and instead use `#pragma once` if your project isn't going I be compiled with gcc.

Comment: Hi, it seems that adding header guards (in either way) on "resource.h" prevents a and b from seeing each other. No identifier error would show up.

Comment: You're obviously doing something wrong then. Post _everything_ that is relevant to this problem in your question. Don't trim down the code. If it's relevant, post it. It sounds like you're hiding something from us.

Comment: I am sorry for confusions I made in this post. The causes of identifier error comes from forward declaration. Nevertheless, your suggestion of adding header guards is working and the self-including problem is solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#pragma once` preprocessor to make resource.h to be included only once in compilation.

Comment: "So I am wondering what causes this error intellisense in VS and if there is anyway to remove it." What causes is already told by compiler and my post answers how to solve(thus remove) it.

Comment: It's obvious that he's not using any guard in resource.h. I don't know what may cause compilation problem in GCC.

Comment: It does have #pragma once preprocessor directive. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.htm this is the patch its un-deprecated

Comment: Hi, adding header guard to resource.h somehow prevent a and b from seeing each other. "expected identifier" error would show up.

Comment: @user2625960: That most probably means that your cyclic dependency problem continues. You may need to do some forward declarations for your classes to prevent it. You may also need to move your code to .cpp to prevent it. I can help if you post a SSCCE(simple compilable) version.

Comment: That works. Additional identifier problem comes from some forward declaration I did not notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`c.h` includes `resource.h` which then itself includes `a.h` and `b.h` which each include `resource.h` again.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating cyclic dependency.
in resource.h you have included a.h , b.h and c.h which is not required.
class files needs resource, resource file does not need class information.